# AMD GPU Driver on Ubuntu

Tags: radeon, amd-graphics, 19.10

I just bought a new laptop with an AMD530-4gb GPU. I searched the internet for a Linux driver and i found nothing. Could anyone here help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need any extra drivers.

Comment: Unfortunatly it seems i need, I tried installing Davinci Resolve but it didn't open showing me an error message related to GPU.
I tried the windows version with amd gpu utilities installed and it worked well

Comment: Unfortunatly it seems i need, I tried installing Davinci Resolve but it didn't open showing me an error message related to GPU.
I tried the windows version with amd gpu utilities installed and it worked well